# Remove rows from a data frame according to a range of row names

Tags: r

I would like to remove from a data.frame all rows from, for example, row number 10 plus the subsequent 4 rows, i.e. from row 10 to row 14.

The starting row for rows removing (in this case the row number 10) results from a test so that I saved the output of the test in `my_test` variable. Briefly I have to remove rows from `my_test` variable plus 4 rows. I tried:

```
myfile_cleaned <- my_original_file[-c(test:test+4),]
```

but it does not work. 
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
myfile_cleaned <- my_original_file[-(test:(test + 4)), ]
```

Due to R's operator precedence, `:` is evaluated before `+`. Therefore you need extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where using the `seq` function is probably better than using `:` both for clarity to the reader, and correctness with precedence.

```
myfile_cleaned <- my_original_file[ -seq( from=test, length.out=5, by=1), ]
```

or

```
myfile_cleaned <- my_original_file[ seq( from= -test, length.out=5, by=-1), ]
```